# Modulus power modulus

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to prove the following property
$$\left | z_{1}^{z_{2}} \right |=\left | z_{1} \right |^{\left | z_{2} \right |}$$
I could do it when $z_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$, but at the moment when I deal with the complexes, I have not been able to see if this property is false or not, I read several questions here and I came to the conclusion of its falsity, but I would like to know if someone can help me with a counterexample, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$\left|2^{-1}\right| \ne  |2|^{|-1|}$

Comment: "as short as can be" answers are rarely better than explanation answers.  You rarely help the asker.  Trying to be clever rarely translate into being effective for the asker.